# Xamarin Forms - Syncfusion SF Schedule swipe Error - iOS only

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, syncfusion

I have a Syncfusion schedule used in month view, but once I swipe to go to the next month the app crashes and shows me this error:

**"Event registration is overwriting existing delegate. Either just use events or your own delegate: Foundation.NSObject UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer+UIGestureRecognizerDelegate"**

This only happens on my iOS project and is fine on Android.

I have no custom renderers associated with the feature.

Would anyone know what is causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

iOS controls have some gesture events and if you use those gesture events you can't add gesture recognizes or the app will crash. So it is likely that SF control is using those events.